# Given an object, which is an array of enum values, how can I get an Enum[] without knowing the enum type

Tags: c#, .net

How can I convert from an object typed variable containing an array of an some enum type to Enum[] ? In other words:

```
// Somewhere in the code we have: public enum MyEnum {This,That};
// Somewhere else in the code we have: public enum TheirEnum {What,Ever};
// In other parts of the code we have additional enum types

// Now, given:
object enumArrayOfSomeType=...; // Maybe it's of type MyEnum[] or TheirEnum[] or 
                                // SomeOtherEnum[]

// I want to say
Enum[] someEnumArray=enumArrayOfSomeType as Enum[];
```

Unfortunately, the code as presented always results in a null value in someEnumArray.

Is there a way to do this?

**Update**:

I guess I was expecting array covariance to kick in, but perhaps I was expecting too much (i.e., array covariance gone wild).

Also, thanks to Chris Sinclair for pointing out in the comments to the accepted answer that covariance of arrays applies **only** to reference types which enums most certainly are not. (See: [.NET Array Covariance rules in MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664572%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).)

Comment: So do you really want something typed as `Enum` at the end or are you wanting to try to work out what the type of the enum is?

Comment: I would really want something to be typed as `Enum[]` at then end, because I am writing a function that gets attributes off of the enum values, regardless of the type of enum (i.e., a pretty generic function).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suspect you'll have to create a new array and cast each element, simply because a `MyEnum[]` is not an `Enum[]`. A simple LINQ query can do this:

```
Enum[] someEnumArray = ((IEnumerable)enumArrayOfSomeType).Cast<Enum>().ToArray();
```

EDIT: Based on your comments, if you simply want to iterate it once and avoid creating an array, you can ditch the `ToArray()` call and treat it as a deferred `IEnumerable<Enum>`:

```
IEnumerable<Enum> someEnumArray = ((IEnumerable)enumArrayOfSomeType).Cast<Enum>();
```

So it essentially will just iterate the elements and cast them one at a time.

EDITx2: From the edited question as to why array covariance doesn't kick in, this is because it's only applicable for *reference types* which enums are not. From the [MSDN 12.5 Array covariance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664572%28v=vs.71%29.aspx):

> For any two *reference-types* A and B, if an implicit reference
>   conversion (Section 6.1.4) or explicit reference conversion (Section
>   6.2.3) exists from A to B, then the same reference conversion also exists from the array type A[R] to the array type B[R]

Comment: Was just about to say something like that but I was a bit slow on making my `object` into the `IEnumerable`.

Comment: Thanks, that certainly does work, at the expense of creating a new array.

Comment: @MichaelGoldshteyn: If you want to avoid creating the array, you can ditch the `ToArray()` call and treat it as `IEnumerable<Enum>`. See my edit.

Comment: This also gave me the idea of maybe just iterating over the array (`IEnumerable` really) with a `foreach` and casting each individual object to `Enum`, then doing what I need to do with the `Enum`. Update: Your edit is a variant of what I was thinking: `foreach (Enum someEnum in enumArrayOfSomeType as IEnumerable)` ...

Comment: @MichaelGoldshteyn: This is essentially what `.Cast<Enum>()` does. (EDIT: at least in the context of casting to/from `object`)

Comment: I was originally expecting array covariance to kick in, but apparently this isn't a case for covariance as .NET interprets it.

Comment: @MichaelGoldshteyn: Nope, not in this case. From the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664572%28v=vs.71%29.aspx): "For any two _reference-types_ A and B, if an implicit reference conversion (Section 6.1.4) or explicit reference conversion (Section 6.2.3) exists from A to B, then the same reference conversion also exists from the array type A[R] to the array type B[R]" This covariance only exists for _reference types_ which, naturally, Enums are not.